# How to write a converted to byte array text file content into another one in java

Tags: java, eclipse, byte, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I converted a text file content to a byte array. I want to rewrite it into another text file but BufferedWriter writes it all in one line how can I fix it? I want that to be exactly like its original

this how I'm doing this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StringToBinary_Converter {
    public static ArrayList<byte[]> al = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("A.txt")));
            String input;
            while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
                al.add(input.getBytes());

            }

            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("B.txt");
            System.setOut(ps);

            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < al.get(i).length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(al.get(i)[j]);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < al.get(i).length; j++) {

    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(al.get(i)[j]))));
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < al.get(i).length; j++) {

    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(al.get(i)[j]))));
                }
            }

            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C.txt"));) {
                for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                    bw.write(new String(al.get(i), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }

}
```

I'm using Eclipse and thanks in advance.

***Edit**
I know it's not needed a conversion to write a file content to another one.

Comment: the `BufferedReader` used for reading does not include the line break a.i.r. Try adding it back to the line that's just been read. That said, copying from one text file to another doesn't need conversion, so one could just write the read lines back out.

Comment: @Joost Papendorp I edited my question sorry it was incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Fix to this:

```
        while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
            al.add(input.getBytes());
            al.add('\n');

        }
```

You are reading by line, so the new line is lost, you need to add it again.

This would do all the work:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StringToBinary_Converter{
    public static ArrayList<byte[]> al = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("A.txt")));
            String input;
            while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
                al.add(input.getBytes());
            }

            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("B.txt");
            System.setOut(ps);

            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                String line = new String(al.get(i));
                for (int j = 0; j < al.get(i).length; j++) {
                    System.out.print((char)al.get(i)[j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: worked exactly how I expected with adding this al.add("\n".getBytes()); thanks

Comment: This still isn't a safe copy operation. For example, This will smash `\r\n` linebreaks into `\n`. Trying to copy e.g. a png with this will probably corrupt it.

Comment: Can't see how PNG files relate with the OP's question where he specified text files

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero it does when reading text files on a different OS than *nix. Using `System.lineSeparator()` fixes that though

Comment: @JoostPapendorp It doesn't. What if you are reading a unix-newlined file on windows? Also, this will mangle characters if you've got the wrong charset encoding, yadayada. If you want to copy a file, copy it - a oneliner from the Files API. byte for byte, not char for char.

Comment: It is clear from the question that the content is only text and no reference to unix-to-windows is needed, unless the OP adds a comment clarifying that. Under OSX and Linux, you will get the same *text result* if you read by line in java a file using \r and add \n to recreate the file. You can test it with the code that I provided (tested under OSX Mojave actually)

Comment: it's a text file that contains some links (like:https://www.google.com/) and in my case, it's working fine.